# Python Selenium, same tables

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I'm trying to find a certain element, and use this code:

```
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//tr[contains(.,'3 - 10:00')] ").text
print(element)
```

However, I have a problem, because there are several tables on the page that have roughly the same content.. So I have more results for the '3 - 10:00'..

The only difference between the tables is as in the picture below:

[image]

Is it possible to extract an item with this content from this specific table called 'Total Points'?

Comment: Your XPath actually is broken because of this `" and "` in the end... Please fix that

Comment: @DejanSamardžija Can you tell us about your _usecase_? Extracting text e.g. **3 - 10:00** by an _xpath_ constructed through the same text `3 - 10:00` doesn't seems to be a valid _usecase_

Comment: @Andersson You are right, I corrected

Comment: @DebanjanB In fact there is another text that is interesting to me, result of my code: '3 - 10:00 37:38 1.909 +2.5 1.769 06/03 09:45'

Answer (score -1):

After many attempts, I solved the problem, very simply:

```
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//div/table)[2]/tbody/tr[contains(.,'3 - 10:00')]").text
```

Thanks for the advice

Comment: Solution using index of table doesn't meet your own requirement described in question